# Почему запрос возращает 500 код состояния?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Помогите разобраться, есть следующий код конроллера на ASP.NET Core

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
  private readonly IRoyalityService _royalityService;

  public RtbController(IRoyalityService royalityService)
        {
           _royalityService = royalityService;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Action()
        {
          //Код контроллера
        }
```

Служба royalityService зарегестрированна в классе `Startup` следующим образом:

```
services.AddSingleton<IRoyalityService, RoyalityService>();
```

Вот код самого интерфейса и класса, который его реализует:

```
public interface IRoyalityService
{
   string CostEncode(decimal value, bool exclude_initialization_vector);
}

public class RoyalityService : IRoyalityService
{
   string _encoder;

   public RoyalityService(byte[] encryption_key, byte[] integrity_key)
   {
      _encoder = // Некий код
   }

   public string CostEncode(decimal value, bool exclude_initialization_vector)
   {
     return // Некий код
   }
}
```

При обращении к данному контроллеру `http://localhost:5000/api/Test` **запрос возращает 500 ошибку** но если убрать из контролера службу `IRoyalityService royalityService`, то ошибки не будет (НО служба нужна), кто нибудь знает, почему может появляться данная ошибка?

Comment: Пользуйтесь логгированием и там вы увидите, что у вашего класса нет конструктора по умолчанию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В классе RoyalityService объявлен конструктор с 2-мя параметрами. Поэтому Di-контейнер просто не может создать его.
Вам надо либо:

1. Добавить конструктор по умолчанию, без параметров;
2. Добавить конструктор, который будет загружать сервис для работы с вашими параметрами.

Всё зависит от того где у вас хранятся параметры encryption_key и integrity_key.

Например, как-то так:

```
public class RoyalitySettings
{
   public byte[] Encryption_key { get; set; }
   
   public byte[] Integrity_key { get; set; }
}

public interface IRoyalitySettingsService
{
   RoyalitySettings LoadSettings();
}

public class RoyalityService : IRoyalityService
{
   string _encoder;

   public RoyalityService(IRoyalitySettingsService settingsService)
   {
      _encoder = // Некий код
   }

   public string CostEncode(decimal value, bool exclude_initialization_vector)
   {
     return // Некий код
   }
}
```

Сервис по работе с настройками также надо будет зарегистрировать в контейнере:

```
services.AddSingleton<IRoyalitySettingsService, RoyalitySettingsService>();
```

Более подробно про внедрение зависимостей можно почитать здесь: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection